# Oracle SQL - Select most recent occurrence of row

Tags: sql, oracle, join, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my current situation: I have a series of subqueries that are building on one another. I have employees whose jobs are to write logs. These logs are then reviewed and edited, and I only want to pull the most recent edits (as each corresponding edit concatenates on top of the one before it.

So if I edit it at 10:00am, and then at 11:00am, the 11:00am edit will ALSO contain the text from the 10:00am, but both values are stored. It is just how our system stores information...can't change it). However, if I join the two tables together, it pulls EVERY edit for the given log.

My issue is that I have MULTIPLE logs, and want to pull only the most recent EDIT for each of the logs. I have tried the following which sort of worked, but it only pulled the OVERALL most recent edit, not the most recent for EACH log:

```
-- I have WITH and the other subqueries above...
sqEDITS AS
(
    SELECT
        Othertable.*, EDIT_TXT
    FROM
        Othertable
    LEFT JOIN 
        EDITS ON Othertable.LOG_NO = EDITS.EDIT_LOG_NO
    WHERE 
        EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT = (SELECT MAX(EDITS.EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT)
                            FROM Othertable, EDITS
                            WHERE Othertable.LOG_NO = EDITS.EDIT_LOG_NO) -- end where
) --end sqEDITS
```

In my test set, there are 35 unique logs, which should return 35 of the most recent edits for each one (if it exists).

My other issue is the TEXT data type, that I am trying to pull, is a CLOB, which makes it hard to work with.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am surely stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Qualify your columns! (Which table does the EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT column belong to?)

Comment: EDITS, so the full table would be EDITS.EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT

I'll make those changes now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Move that condition from WHERE to ON. (I.e simply replace WHERE with AND.)

Comment: Hi, jarlh. That did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT othertable.*, edit_txt
FROM othertable -- Get logs (?)
LEFT JOIN ( -- Get most recent edit for each log
    SELECT edit_txt
    FROM (
        SELECT edit_txt
        FROM edits
        WHERE RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY edit_log_no ORDER BY edit_activity_dt DESC) = 1 -- For each log_no, only return most recent edit (based on edit_activity_dt value)
    ) edits
) edits ON othertable.log_no = edits.edit_log_no
```

Let me know if that works.

**Update**
This should work:

```
SELECT othertable.*, edit_txt
FROM othertable -- Get logs (?)
LEFT JOIN ( -- Get most recent edit for each log
    SELECT edit_txt, edit_log_no
    FROM (
      SELECT edit_txt, edit_log_no, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY edit_log_no ORDER BY edit_activity_dt DESC) EditRank
      FROM edits
    ) src
    WHERE EditRank = 1
) edits ON othertable.log_no = edits.edit_log_no
```

You could move the "WHERE EditRank = 1" to the JOIN condition and get rid of a sub-select.  Not sure if this would improve performance, but readability would be easier.

Comment: Thanks, ravioli. I appreciate your response. Could you explain what a window function is? It sort of looks like combining the WITH...AS subquery method I was using with the analytic function for rank, as mentioned below. I hope to one day learn enough to help others like you are with me!

Comment: Window functions are similar to aggregate functions (SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG).  The difference is they allow you to process groups of rows within your result set, based on the PARTITION BY expression.  If you don't include a PARTITION BY expression, then they return the values for the entire row set.  It's a bit dry, but take a look at this Oracle-specific link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html.  You can also search for "window functions"

Comment: Ahh okay - thank you! I did just try to run it, and it looks like whoever configured our DBMS bungled it and it errors out telling me that window-type functions aren't allowed here, so it looks like that avenue is closed :(

Thank you for trying though! :)

Comment: Can you think of any method to try and get to this? Below, Gordon's method ran without problem but unfortunately did not return the same number of rows. There were a few instances where the same log was returned multiple times.

Comment: Yes, gimme one second :)

Comment: Give it another try.  I added a sub-select to remove the window function from the WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi, ravioli. Thank you so much for your help!! You are certainly helping me learn a lot, I have to give that to you.

Unfortunately...I am still having trouble. It tells me that edits.edit_log_no is an invalid identifier, so it doesn't see it. I tried adding it to the select statement, and I also tried moving around some parenthesis, but I'm having no luck. I even took the triple sure case of triple checking spelling to avoid any rookie errors :)

I can continue to mess around with it...but I would greatly appreciate your continued support.

Comment: I found out where the error was. 
 "edits ON othertable.log_no = edits.edit_log_no" should be: " edits ON othertable.log_no = src.edit_log_no"

However, it still tells me that window functions are not allowed :(

Regardless, thanks a lot so far for your help with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162360/discussion-between-ravioli-and-tony-kelly).

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, the problem is that the subquery references two tables.  I think you intend a correlated subquery:

```
sqEDITS AS (
         SELECT Othertable.*, EDIT_TXT
         FROM Othertable LEFT JOIN
              EDITS
              ON Othertable.LOG_NO = EDITS.EDIT_LOG_NO
        WHERE EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT = 
              (SELECT MAX(EDITS.EDIT_ACTIVITY_DT)
               FROM EDITS
               WHERE Othertable.LOG_NO = EDITS.EDIT_LOG_NO
              ) -- end where
       ) --end sqEDITS
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff. I am going to try this out and I will get right back to you.

Comment: Gordon, it looks like that when I view all of my logs BEFORE trying to add in their edit text, I have 35 unique samples I am testing from. However, after running this, I have 51 -- so I do have some duplicates in some places.

Answer (score 0):

You should use analytic function for rank.

```
SELECT columna,columnb FROM (
  SELECT columna,columnb
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY columna ORDER BY (column of date ) DESC) AS  RNK   
       FROM  table 
) WHERE RNK=1
```

Comment: Hi, Aydin Ozgur. Thanks a lot for your comment. I will go ahead and try this out in just a few minutes and get back to you.